# File downloaded from url with Carrierwave but "nil" field in my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm integrating a video section in my small CMS. 
I create a new video, I put the url in a form input field and then I must save the video url and also a thumbnail. Uusually videos are from Vimeo and Youtube.

I'm using CarrierWave to download thumb from url.

My Video model is this (simplified)

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :thumb_url, VideoThumbUploader

  before_save :save_thumb_url

  private

    def save_thumb_url
      self.remote_thumb_url_url = extract_thumb
    end

    def extract_thumb
      thumb_url = if is_youtube_video?
        youtube_thumb_url
      elsif is_vimeo_video?
        vimeo_thumb_url
      else
        'http://placehold.it/100x100'
      end
    end
  end
```

In my folder I have the downloaded thumbnail, but the thumb_url column of my db is empty: when I save my form _thumb_url is NIL.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1078

It's an issue. Here the workaround!